# UIViewAnimation with constraint not working in Swift

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewanimation

I am trying to create an animation where I want to slide a uiview from right to left once parent UIViewController has loaded although I am able to display the view but the animation is not working. My code for animation:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    view.isOpaque = false
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 1.0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.contentXConstraint.constant = 500
        self.contentXConstraint.constant = 80
    }) { (status) in

    }
}
```

I have displayed the parent view controller as presented viewcontroller:

```
present(navController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()`

```
self.contentXConstraint.constant = 500
self.contentXConstraint.constant = 80

UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 1.0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
   self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}) { (status) in
}
```

from https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622507-layoutifneeded

> Use this method to force the view to update its layout immediately. When using Auto Layout, the layout engine updates the position of views as needed to satisfy changes in constraints

Comment: @pankaj Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Move your animation code from viewDidAppear to viewDidLayoutSubviews

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `layoutIfNeeded()` method after updating constraints

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    view.isOpaque = false
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 1.0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.contentXConstraint.constant = 500
        self.contentXConstraint.constant = 80
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }) { (status) in

    }
}
```